# How to use .env file variables with typescript?

Tags: typescript, dotenv

I am saving my jwt token secret into the `.env` file.

```
JWT_SECRET="secretsecret"
```

Now when I try to fetch the value using `process.env.JWT_SECRET` I get error as

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'
```

I am trying to learn typescript but facing this issue with `.env` please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, to load the environment constants (`.env` file) into your program you must install `dotenv` (`npm install dotenv --save`) and add the following into the `.ts` file:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

Note: set it at the top of the `.ts` file.

Comment: I would also recommend `dotenv-flow`, which builds on `dotenv` to add support for local overrides in `.env.local`. This is helpful in most typical shared repositories, so you check in global config in `.env` and allow each developer to add custom overrides in `.env.local` that's omitted from source control. It also adds support for `.env.${NODE_ENV}` for environment-specific config, which is a nice starting point for multiple deployments.

Comment: @superhawk610 exactly what I was searching for. We can't use `nestjs` in some of our libraries, but we still want the local and env-specific configs. Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question ^ he's able to get the constants, but its the wrong type. The lower answer is the correct one

Answer (score 2):

The error is arising because a parameter of type`Secret` is required but `process.env.JWT_SECRET` is of type `string|undefined`

To resolve this issue `import {Secret} from "jsonwebtoken"`
and add `process.env.JWT_SECRET as Secret` instead of just `process.env.JWT_SECRET`

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are supported out of the box with Node and are accessible via the env object (which is a property of the process global object.)

To see this in action, you can create your own environment variable right in the Node REPL by appending a variable to the process.env object directly.

To create environment variables in your Node app, you will probably want to use a package like DotEnv.

DotEnv is a lightweight npm package that automatically loads environment variables from a .env file into the process.env object.

To use DotEnv, first install it using the command: `npm i dotenv` Then in your app, require and configure the package like this: `require('dotenv').config()`

You can declare multiple variables in the .env file. For example, you could set database-related environment variables like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

There is no need to wrap strings in quotation marks. DotEnv does this automatically for you.

Accessing your variables is super easy! They are attached to the process.env object, so you can access them using the pattern process.env.KEY.

[image]